# Solving IVP $y'=t|y|^\alpha, \ y(0)=1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

**Intro**: This is a follow up to my post [Application of Picard-Lindelöf to determine uniqueness of a solution to an IVP](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/777114/application-of-picard-lindelof-to-determine-uniqueness-of-a-solution-to-an-ivp), where I am trying to verify that the below IVP has a unique solution in some interval that includes $0$. This is a nightmare and doesn't work out for me. So I try to go the opposite direction and see whether or not I can come up with something.

I hope it's okay to make this kind of a follow up post, if not please feel free to close it. I also hope someone finds the time to quickly look through this post and tell me whether or not my reasoning is correct.

> **Problem**: Solve the following IVP $$ \begin{cases} y' &= t|y|^\alpha \\ y(0)&=1 \end{cases} $$ where $ \alpha \neq 1$

**My approach**: This is the first time I am dealing with an absolute value function, so I guess it is reasonable to look into the two cases where $y$ is positive and $y$ is (strictly) negative.

I first want to show that I can divide through the expression $y^\alpha$.

Let $y=0$ then $y'=0 \implies y=c$ but $y(0)=1$ and therefore $c=1 \implies y=1$ which is a contradiction, thus $y \neq 0$. Then I start solving the differential equation. $$ \frac{dy}{dt}=ty^\alpha \iff \frac{dy}{y^\alpha}=tdt \implies \frac{y^{1- \alpha}}{1-\alpha}=\frac{t^2}{2}+C \\ \implies y = \left( \frac{(1-\alpha)t^2}{2}+K \right)^\frac{1}{1-\alpha} $$
Applying initial conditions would lead to $K=1$. Is that correct? Now the same for $y$ negative of course which I will save for now, just substituting $|y|=-y$ into the original IVP.

How could these results resemble uniqueness?

**Update**: A sudden idea striking me, it seems very tedious but do I need to do a check analysis for $\alpha$? Meaning do the above calculations for $\alpha < 0$, likewise $\alpha > 1$ and $\alpha \in ]0,1[$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that $t\,|y|^\alpha>0$ if $t>0$ and $t\,|y|^\alpha<0$ if $t<0$. This implies that the solution is decreasing to the left of $t=0$ and increasing to the right of $t=0$. In particular $y(t)\ge1$ for all $t$ for which the solution is defined. The function $t\,|y|^\alpha$ is continuous and locally Lipschitz (as a function of $y$) on $D=(-\infty,\infty)\times[1/2,\infty)$. Since the solution never leaves $D$, the solution is unique, and your formula is valid for all $\alpha\ne1$. Observe that if $\alpha>1$, then the solution is defined only for $|t|<\sqrt{2/(\alpha-1)}$.